# What type of plot should I use for the poker equity visualization?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, histogram, poker

I need to visualize the poker equity (the expectation that one poker hand is more likely to win against another hand). Here is the exact example what I need to do [Visualizing Hold'em Hands](http://chrisbeaumont.org/holdem_odds/). What type of matplotlib or another python visualization library I should use for this purpose. Is it histogram2d or scatter, or what?

Comment: You could use a `hist2d` if your raw data is a list of all possible combinations. Or you can use an `imshow` if your raw data is already aggregated.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest thanks for the imshow hint! I have found in imshow help that things that I need is called "categorical  heatmap"

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the @ImportanceOfBeingErnest comment.  I have found in imshow help that plot that I need is called "categorical heatmap" and could be done done by the imshow.